# Is the word "loading" user-friendly?

Tags: copywriting, loading, ux-writing

Working on a feature for our app that tells the user when the app is loading. We want to include a loading spinner icon, and I think accompanying the icon with just the word "Loading" is very straightforward for the user. I'm worried though that Loading sounds very technical and using more descriptive copy like "Please wait while blank is happening" would be more user-friendly.

Is just "Loading" too technical?

Comment: Is this when the app itself is loading after the user opens it (first thing the user sees), or someplace inside the app that is loading data?  Or both?

Comment: yes, it's user friendly. But it highly depends on what @Izquierdo asked

Comment: Spinning wheel, dots or "loading...". Letting me wait is not user-friendly. When I evaluate a new application this is one of the thing that I consider not user-friendly and it is for me a do-not-buy signal. But a spinning or moving dots wheel is more user-friendly if you not speak english.

Answer (score 1):

This article from NN Group is worth reading about progress indicators. [Progress Indicators](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progress-indicators/).

"Please wait while blank is happening" is indeed more user-friendly. Just the word Loading could make the user think it's stuck after waiting for a while.